# Collision detection with sprites from an array in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

i'm pretty new to Objective-C and Cocos2D so go easy, I know this is basic stuff.

I'm using an array to randomly place 4 gold coin sprites on the screen, and i'm using another sprite (a dragon) to fly around and collect the coins. Obviously, I want the coin to disappear and another to randomly appear (like collecting apples in Snake). My problem is that I don't know how to reference the individual sprites. I've added some handling to the update method but a) I don't think its appropriate and b) it doesn't do anything.  Please help. I think I need to utilise:

```
[self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];
```

But I'm not sure how. This is how i'm populating the screen with rings::

```
@implementation MainScene {

CCSprite *_hero;
CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
CCSprite *_goldRing;
NSMutableArray *_goldRings;

}

-(void)didLoadFromCCB {

self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

_goldRing.physicsBody.collisionType = @"Level";
_goldRing.physicsBody.sensor = TRUE;

_physicsNode.collisionDelegate = self;
_hero.physicsBody.collisionType = @"hero";

CGFloat random = ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX);   
_meteorites = [NSMutableArray array];
[self spawnNewGoldRing];
[self spawnNewGoldRing];
[self spawnNewGoldRing];
[self spawnNewGoldRing];

}

-(void)spawnNewGoldRing {

CGFloat randomX = ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX);
CGFloat randomY = ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX);
CGFloat rangeX = 200;
CGFloat rangeY = 300;

CCNode *goldRing = [CCBReader load:@"goldRing"];
goldRing.position = ccp(randomX * rangeX, (randomY * rangeY)+100);
[_physicsNode addChild:goldRing];
[_goldRings addObject:goldRing];
}

- (void)update:(CCTime)delta {

_hero.position = ccp(_hero.position.x, _hero.position.y);

if(_hero.position.x <= _hero.contentSize.width/2 * -1.5) {
    _hero.position = ccp(_ground.contentSize.width + _hero.contentSize.width/2, _hero.position.y);

    NSMutableArray *collectedGoldRings = nil;
    for (CCNode *goldRing in _goldRings) {
        CGPoint goldRingWorldPosition = [_physicsNode convertToWorldSpace:goldRing.position];
        CGPoint goldRingScreenPosition = [self convertToNodeSpace:goldRingWorldPosition];
        if (goldRingScreenPosition.x < -goldRing.contentSize.width) {
            if (!collectedGoldRings) {
                collectedGoldRings = [NSMutableArray array];
            }
            [collectedGoldRings addObject:goldRing];
        }
    }
    for (CCNode *goldRingToRemove in collectedGoldRings) {
        [goldRingToRemove removeFromParent];
        [_goldRings removeObject:goldRingToRemove];
        // for each removed goldRing, add a new one
        [self spawnNewGoldRing];
    }

}

}
```

Would it be too much to ask how to keep count of these too to display a score?

Thanks so much for any help.

EDIT*

NSLog on the array of gold rings

```
"<goldRing = 0x9b756b0 | Rect = (0.00,0.00,24.00,23.50) | tag =  | atlasIndex = -1>"
)
2014-05-08 10:24:32.201 dragonCollector2[10165:60b] Gold Ring Loaded
2014-05-08 10:24:32.201 dragonCollector2[10165:60b] Array:(
"<goldRing = 0x9b77e50 | Rect = (0.00,0.00,24.00,23.50) | tag =  | atlasIndex = -1>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you are using spritebuilder, so you are using the new version of Cocos2D.
In this version you can track a collision between two types of nodes. In your case, the coins and the hero.

This is as simple as:

1) Set your  `coin.physicsBody.collisionType = @"coin";`

2) Set your  `hero.physicsBody.collisionType = @"hero";`

3) Implement this method:

```
-(void)ccPhysicsCollisionPostSolve:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair hero:(CCNode *)nodeA coin:(CCNode *)nodeB{

//this method will be automatically called when the hero hits a coin.
//now call your method to remove the coin and call the method to add another coin.
}
```

To keep a count of the score, just make an int variable, `int score;`. In your didLoadFromCCB method, initialize it to 0, `score=0;` and inside this collision method, just do `score++;` and maybe do a `NSLog(@"Your score:%i",score);`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

for things like that, you do not need to use physics. When your hero will touch a coin, just update the user score (it could be an integer) and the coin position.
in your update method do something like

```
for(CCSprite *gold in _goldRings){
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(_hero.boundingBox,gold.boundingBox)){
        //touched a coin
        //do whatever u want
        //do not remove the coin from the array, just change it's position!
        _userPoints += 1;
        gold.position=ccp(arc4random()%200 , arc4random()%300);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like where this is going, however using the suggested code, no collision is detected. The _hero is a CCSprite and the _goldRing is a CCNode as it is loaded from a goldRing class. I spawned two gold rings and took a log of the array which confuses me, as their coordinates seem local. Does this affect the boundingBox??

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up using the ccPhysicsCollisionPostSolve method and removing the children as they are collided with, then respawning another ring. It was document quite well in the PeevedPenguins tutorial. Thanks again.